# How to replace default dialog boxes in Rails 3 with JQuery UI Dialog?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui

We are a startup working on an application and we are using Rails 3 and JQuery as our technology.
We need help to replace default confirm dialog boxes in rails.ujs with JQuery UI Dialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This certainly requires some work that is not made "out of the box". You have to understand the basics of what you are asking.

First of all, you click on a link that has `:confirm => "Are you sure?"`, which adds the `data-confirm` attribute to your html tag. Then, you have a event listener binded on all elements which have a `data-confirm` attribute, and simply does a `confirm` of the attribute value ("Are you sure?"). If the user click yes, nothing happens, which means that the link is followed. If the user click cancel, the event is cancelled and the link is not followed.

What you want to do is to break this behavior. You want to store whatever action was called, cancel the current event. Then, use the jquery dialog, and depending on the user choice, call that action again or do nothing.

You can't simply replace the `confirm` with a jquery dialog because the browser won't wait for the jquery dialog answer, as it does for the `confirm` box.

Hope that helped you understand the basic of what you are going to implement.

Comment: Thanks Dominic for solving my query :)